# How do i find b?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation of the line joining the complex numbers $-5 + 4i$ and $7 + 2i$ can be expressed in the form
$az + b \overline{z} = 38$ for some complex numbers $a$ and $b$. Find the ordered pair $(a, b)$.

I got 6 - 15i for "a" but im not sure if it is right.

Comment: What did you get for $b$? If your ordered pair $(a,b)$ works when you plug in $z=-5+4i$ and also works when you plug in $z=7+2i$, then you have the right answer.

Comment: idk how to get b

Comment: How did you get $a$? The same method should work to get $b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z, z_1, z_2$ lie on a line then $arg\frac{(z-z_1)}{(z_2-z_1)}=0$ or $\pi$

$ \Rightarrow \frac{(z-z_1)}{(z_2-z_1)}$ is purely real

$ \Rightarrow \frac{(z-z_1)}{(z_2-z_1)}=\frac{(\overline z-\overline z_1)}{(\overline z_2-\overline z_1)}$

$ (\overline z_2-\overline z_1)(z-z_1)=(\overline z-\overline z_1)(z_2-z_1) $

$ (\overline z_2-\overline z_1)z -(z_2-z_1)\overline z= \overline z_2 z_1-\overline z_1 z_2$

Putting in the values of $z_1, z_2$ we get $(1-6i)z+(1+6i)\overline z=38$